Antd Slider not dragging via it's tooltip on mobile devices (working on PC)
I am using the slider component from antd (version ^5.11.1): https://ant.design/components/slider
The issue I'm facing is that the slider is not dragging via the tooltip on touch screen devices, but it works fine when dragged using a mouse on laptops, computers, etc. I'm not sure what the problem is so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Slider component
     <Slider
        range={{ draggableTrack: false }}
        max={11}
        min={-1}
        defaultValue={[-1, 11]}
        value={[Number.parseInt(value[0]), Number.parseInt(value[1])]}
        step={1}
        tooltip={{
          open: true,
          zIndex: 100,
          arrow: false,
          rootClassName: "slider-pointer-event",
          className: "font-weight-bold ",
          color: "#28bdbb",
          placement: "bottom",
          autoAdjustOverflow: false,
          formatter: noformatter,
        }}
        onChange={onChange}
      />


I test it in the antd playground with the latest version and it works as expected... Can you try to upgrade to antd latest version?
